Utilizing Google Colab w/Google Cloud w/python to generate pictures and am receiving an error when i try to use a seed
I am learning to use AI and am utilizing Colab, Python, and Google Cloud. I am able to successfully generate images with the following code:
Setup:
!pip install --quiet --upgrade --user google-cloud-aiplatform

import IPython
import time
app = IPython.Application.instance()
app.kernel.do_shutdown(True)
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
import vertexai
vertexai.init(project="$PROJECT_ID", location = "us-central1")
from vertexai.preview.vision_models import ImageGenerationModel
model = ImageGenerationModel.from_pretrained("imagegeneration@005")
!pip install --upgrade watermark

Working generation code:


response = model.generate_images(
prompt = '''A flower.''',
number_of_images = 2
)

The issue is when I try and use a seed:


model.watermark_enabled = False
response = model.generate_images(
prompt = '''A flower.''',
number_of_images = 2,
seed = 42
)
I recieve this:

 

    _InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
         71         try:
    ---> 72             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
         73         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
    
    8 frames
    _InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        details = "Image generation failed with the following error: Seed is not supported when watermark is enabled."
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.141.95:443 {created_time:"2024-05-23T14:53:50.497705026+00:00", grpc_status:3, grpc_message:"Image generation failed with the following error: Seed is not supported when watermark is enabled."}"
    >
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    InvalidArgument                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
         72             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
         73         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
    ---> 74             raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
         75 
         76     return error_remapped_callable
    
    InvalidArgument: 400 Image generation failed with the following error: Seed is not supported when watermark is enabled.

[Error report](https://i.sstatic.net/mZ0FbeDs.png)


When the error first occured I added this:

model.watermark_enabled = False

When it didn't work, i did the opposite:


model.watermark_enabled = True
When that failed I ran this and went through the two options above:


!pip install --upgrade watermark


I got the same error and found an add_watermark=False as a parameter of the generate_images.
response = model.generate_images(
    prompt = '''A flower.''',
    number_of_images = 2,
    seed = 42,
    add_watermark=False,
)

